# I am trying to use selenium python to click an element in chrome new tab, but I am getting error no such element even thought the element is there

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got all the right modules that I need and my code looks pretty good.I am trying to click the add shortcut button using selenium, it is my first time using selenium, but I am pretty sure I did all of the code right. This is all of my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('chrome://newtab')
add_button = driver.find_element_by_id('addShortcut')
add_button.click()
```

This is the chrome elements:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0DJR.png
This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Srikar's Stuff\Programming\Python\WebScraper.py", line 7, in <module>
    add_button = driver.find_element_by_id('addShortcut')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="addShortcut"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Is it an error with my code or something else?
Help!!??

Comment: Open your inspector and ensure which is your absolut refference of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Google is using the feature of [Shadow Root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot). It hides what is under it as an Iframe. I found the following workaround:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('chrome://newtab')
delay = 1 # seconds
js_query = "return document.getElementsByTagName('ntp-app')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('mostVisited').shadowRoot"
try:
    _ = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'ntp-app')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
    
most_visited = driver.execute_script(js_query)
add_button = most_visited.find_element_by_id('addShortcut')
add_button.click()
```

This should work though it is a little bit hacky

Comment: Never mind it did not work. I get the error 'add_button = most_visited.find_element_by_id('addShortcut')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id' and the code i used is:

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: This is the code: 'import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('chrome://newtab')
js_query = "return document.getElementsByTagName('ntp-app')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('mostVisited').shadowRoot"
most_visited = driver.execute_script(js_query)
add_button = most_visited.find_element_by_id('addShortcut')
add_button.click()'
'

Comment: Every time I run it, it gives me a different error, sometimes it works but other it says attribute not found or others times it gives some random shadowroot error

Comment: Do you know what happened? Is it a problem with the code or my device?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that you have to wait for the page to be fully loaded. Can you try with the new code? What I am doing is that I am checking every second if the element `ntp-app` is in the DOM, and if it is, I am continuing the script.

Answer (score 0):

The icons aren't on that page.  They're in an `<iframe>` called `chrome-untrusted://new-tab-page/custom_background_image?url=`, and I don't think you can bring that up on its own.  Why would you want to?  Unless you login, this Chrome isn't connected to your desktop Chrome.

Comment: I think you inspected the wrong element, the element `addShortcut` is not in the iframe but beneath it

Comment: I inspected the add shortcut again and the id is addShortcut and there is no other thing i can do, if there is then can you send a screenshot or example?

Comment: @SrikarAnumolu My comment was about the answer provided :)